# Android Market statistics: "This is inclusive of updates"

Tags: google-play

In the "Statistics" link of each application I have published in Google's Android Market, the install counts is described as:

> Total active installs represents the
>   number of devices on which the
>   application is currently installed.
>   This is inclusive of updates.

Does this mean that if a user installs and updates twice, only 1 will get counted? It would be the most natural way to count, but somehow I fail to understand *"This is inclusive of updates"* so it makes me doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x0n's answer was true until 18 October 2011, but now [Market says](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/support/bin/answer.py?answer=1711311):

> As of 18 October 2011 developers may notice a decrease in the active
>   install counts displayed in their Android Market Developer Console.
>   Some app updates were being counted as active installs. We are now
>   using a different calculation methodology which does not incorporate
>   installing an app update. Going forward the active installs metric
>   will correctly reflect the device installations. Please note that
>   total install counts were not affected.

Strangely, the statistics page's footnote still says:

> Total active installs represents the number of devices on which the
>   application is currently installed. This is inclusive of updates.

I reported this incoherence to Google.

Comment: Hah I came here because I saw -15 in my stats. Is it really right to take points off me because I am no longer correct? My answer was correct then. I think an update/addendum to foot of the question would be more appropriate. Grumpy snort.

Comment: @x0n -15? ouch, sorry about that, I did not think that would do this. Should check meta to learn what it is the sensible thing to do in those cases. Giving you +10 now, so in the end this question has gotten you +30 net. Even though changing the accepted answer costs a penalty and won't bring me any point, I felt I had to do it for the sake of correctness.

Answer (score 3):

No, it means that if a user installs once and updates once, it appears as two installs on the market. This is obviously favourable for Android to inflate statistics.

Comment: Really?? Doesn't this fact make the number of active installs totally useless as a way of measuring? We would have to divide by the number of updates we've published and take into account that some users may not choose to update the app..

Comment: Well it's good for publishers to boast too. If you want to know how many de-facto first time installs, count your purchases. Ultimately the appstore sees a download of the full app. Whether it's an update or not is a detail on the client side.

Comment: Sure. Still, one thing is what they boast on the public pages. On my private publisher dashboard I, as a publisher, am more interested in the hard facts. It would've been easy for Google to track both first-time installs *and* upgrades. They're not only seeing downloads, there is also a ping-back from the client. Otherwise they wouldn't be able to track active installs. Well, my app is free so counting purchases is a noop. Guess I will have to build my own tracking infrastructure in order to be in control.